# How to revert mistakenly made transactions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

This is a general question but to make it a bite more concrete let us say you have a table like this in SQL Server database:

```
ORDER (ID, CUSTOMER, ...)
```

Now you want to do an update on a single row like this:

```
UPDATE ORDER
SET CUSTOMER = 'NewGuyInTown'
WHERE ID = '1'
```

By mistake you query only the first two lines so your query looks like this:

```
UPDATE ORDER
SET CUSTOMER = 'NewGuyInTown'
```

Result would be, that CUSTOMER of all rows in ORDER will be set to 'NewGuyInTown' of course.

I am happy it did never happen to me but is there a way to find those transactions and do a rollback in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

**Edit**

I know you can do

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
ROLLBACK
```

to see number of affected rows.

You also can do a backup before update.

But what to do if someone will ever do it as described before and change all the data mistakenly?

Comment: Use transactions on updates so you can roll them back.

Comment: I always use transactions on productive databases because this scenario should never happen.

Comment: Always check your `UPDATE`  statements before you run them; run them as a `SELECT` to see the rows that would be updated. And if your stats is that important, use the full backup model and do regular backups, and transaction log backups.

Comment: "But what to do if someone will ever do it as described before and change all the data mistakenly?" -- Restore from backup.

Comment: One safeguard you can use is to utilize a third party plugin. Most of them have a feature to warn or prevent updates with no where clause. I use SQL Prompt from Redgate which has this feature.

Comment: Restore from backup.  Or manually parse the transaction log and craft UPDATES to undo the changes.  But that's a pain.  Restore is easier.

Comment: This reminds me of one of my first jobs. We were a large company with offices all over the US. We had an update trigger on the Employee table that would disable the AD account when an employees status was changed to no longer employeed. I had only been at this job about a month and was asked to change the status of an employee and I forgot the where clause. This fired off that trigger and disabled the AD account of the entire company. Made for several long days.

Comment: @SeanLange That is why I ask. Heard several of those stories. Thought I could be prepared if it ever happens ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert transactions using the `ROLLBACK` keyword.

The syntax would be:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE ORDER
SET CUSTOMER = 'NewGuyInTown';
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

See also: [How to roll back UPDATE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518779/how-to-roll-back-update-statement)

Comment: Thank you. I already use this to check number of updated rows before I run it without rollback. Want to know if there is a way when someone did not do it.

Comment: @otto, short of restoring a backup, no!

Answer (score 3):

Unless `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` checkbox in Options is unselected, SQL command executions will make permanent change to the data in your database. So, there is no way to know the state of the database prior to the execution of the statement or the rows that were affected by the execution, unless you had a backup of the database state prior to the execution of such statements.

If that checkbox is unselected, then you can open another query window and see the state of the records and be able to compare the output in that window with the output in the window where the statements are run. And then, there are a number of Do's and Don'ts on executing SQL statements directly on the database like this to prevent accidental unintended modifications to the data! HTH.